# Umbraco modifies html when saving. How do I get it to just accept what I wrote?

Tags: umbraco, autocorrect

I’m experiencing issues on several pages in Umbraco, where I cannot use an ordered list with an unordered list beneath it.

Everything appears correctly in the interface screen. However, when I save and preview/publish, the bulleted lists become numbered lists. I tried editing the HTML, and that didn’t help. Umbraco kept “correcting” it.

Comment: What version of Umbraco are using?

Comment: This because of the TinyMCe editor doing a lot of tidying. I have a smiliar problem here: http://our.umbraco.org/forum/using/ui-questions/7697-Cannon-enter-full-URL-in-text-in-tinyMCE but have not found a way to turn off tidying completely.

Answer (score 0):

So, after you publish the document, if you refresh the back end, has your actual mark-up changed? If not, then you are just having a simple css issue, but if the markup changes, then Andreas is correct, its the html tidying that changes your markup.